# link_to_remote attributes/arguments in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript, rails-3-upgrade

I'm trying to upgade from rails 2.3 to 3.0 and I've found that `link_to_remote` in rails 2 should be changed to `link_to` in rails 3 with `:remote => true` attribute.

And unobtrusive javascript(UJS) for `:before, :loading, :failure, :update`

But I also have attributes like `:url, :href, :title` **how am I supposed to change that** ?

Here is the rails 2.3 code I'm trying to upgrade

```
 <%= link_to_remote column.label,
  { :url => sort_params,
    :before => "addActiveScaffoldPageToHistory('#{href}', '#{controller_id}')",
    :loading => "Element.addClassName('#{column_header_id}','loading');",
    :failure => "ActiveScaffold.report_500_response('#{active_scaffold_id}')",
    :update => active_scaffold_content_id,
    :method => :get },
  { :href => href ,
   :title => column.header_info}%>
```

I've analysed lot of websites and Rails documentation but nothing has specified about these attributes for `link_to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind callbacks to remote links in Rails 3, the rest of the attributes can be assigned as options.

```
link_to column.label,
  sort_params,
  remote: true,
  title: column_header.info,
  id: 'my_remote_link',
  data: {
    href: href,
    controller_id: controller_id,
    column_header_id: column_header_id,
    active_scaffold_id: active_scaffold_id
  }
```

We'll use the data-attributes for the callbacks.

```
$('#my_remote_link').bind('ajax:beforeSend, function() {
  addActiveScaffoldPageToHistory($('#my_remote_link').data('href'), $('#my_remote_link').data('controller_id'));
});
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events for a description of the different ajaxEvents.